# How to combine two columns in single column?

Tags: sql, db2

Using DB2 database

```
colum1 column2 
---------------
   1       A
   2       B
```

Need output like this:

```
colum3
-------
   1
   2
   A
   B
```

Comment: Do a UNION ALL. Note that the data types must match, so cast may be needed.

Comment: Thanks...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT cast(colum1 as varchar) AS colum3 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(colum2 as varchar) AS colum3 FROM table
```